# Table Compression and clusterd index compresison

Tags: sql-server, indexing, compression

I'm almost 100% sure there isn't any, but just to confirm.

Is there any difference between applying compression to a table and applying compression to the table's clustered index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No effective difference. The data *is* the index at the lowest level of the B-Tree index structure.

The tree of the index is typically tiny compared to the data: I don't know if this compresses

Comment: +1According to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx) the *non–leaf-level pages do not receive page compression*.